# Help Creating Shape of Object with Path

Tags: bezier-curves, path

I think it would first be helpful to describe the object I'm trying to make: I am attempting a stylized comet that is looping around the earth. I want the ring that is rotating the earth to be "flat" (still bulbish and solid) while the end that connects to the comet I wanted to be more round.

Essentially, I know you can manipulate a bezier curve and path to make things like cool roots and horns, but the caveat is those are using one consistent shape, while I'm trying to go from flat to round.

For reference in the example, I want squish the highlighted curves left side to match the style of the one under it, while keeping the round tube like shape on the right side.

[image: Sample]

Hopefully this makes sense! Please help! Any ideas?

Comment: hello, so it's supposed to be like the bottom one except at its end where it is supposed to be like the top one? is it supposed to be a small radius like the top one? You could use a lattice to deform it